# In Qt how can I center a button in a gridlayout?

Tags: qt

In this code, how can I center the button inside the gridlayout?

```
QPushButton* button_example = new QPushButton(this);
button_example->setText("Click");
QGridLayout *gl_example = new QGridLayout(this);
gl_example->addWidget(button_example);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this use `centralWidget` and also add `Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter)` :

```
QPushButton *button_example = new QPushButton(centralWidget());
button_example->setText("Click");
QGridLayout *gl_example = new QGridLayout(centralWidget());
gl_example->addWidget(button_example, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

**output:**

[image]